# Visual Basic Avg. Temp Calculator

Tags: vb.net

Ok, so I am super new to visual basic and was not planning on taking it as a class either until they made it a requirement for me to get my technicians certificate at my community college. Literally understand the chapters I have read so far to a T, and then first homework assignment comes up and for the past few days I have been scratching my head as to why on earth it is not working. Here is what the Prof is asking.

> Write a program that calculates average daily temperatures and summary statistics. The user will be prompted to enter a Fahrenheit temperature as a value with one decimal place and to select the name of the technician entering the temperature. The user will have the option to see the Celsius equivalent of the entered Fahrenheit temperature. The program will display the average temperature of all entered temperatures. The results are displayed when the user hits ENTER, uses the access key or clicks the Calculate button. The user will be given the opportunity to enter another temperature when the user hits ESC (Clear is the Cancel Button), uses the access key or clicks the Clear button. The user will exit the program by clicking the Exit button or using its access key. The Exit button will also display the summary statistics: 1) the number of temperatures entered by each technician and 2) the average temperature of all entered temperatures. Calculations should only be done if a numeric value between 32.0 and 80.0 (inclusive) degrees for temperature is entered and a technician has been selected.

The graphical side is a breeze with dragging and dropping, then naming the labels, radio buttons, etc... But now that I have assembled my code. Nothing is working. I'm frustrated, confused, and let down. I had no idea this class would be this hard. Here is what I came up with so far code wise. No error messages at all, just not getting any output pretty much.

```
Option Strict On
Option Strict On    

Public Class Form1


Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

    'Clear App
    txtTemp.Clear()
    lblAverageTemp.Text = String.Empty
    lblCelsius.Text = String.Empty
    radDave.Checked = False
    radJoe.Checked = False
    chkCelsiusTemp.Checked = False
    'New Temp Focus
    txtTemp.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click

    'End app with display
    MessageBox.Show("Dave entered intEntriesDave entries." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Joe    entered intEntriesJoe entries." & _
    ControlChars.CrLf & "The average temperature is _.", "Status")
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Public Sub chkCelsiusTemp_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkCelsiusTemp.CheckedChanged

    'Convert entered Fahrenheit temp to Celsius
    Dim dblCelsius As Double
    dblCelsius = (CDbl(txtTemp.Text) - 32) * 5 / 9
    lblCelsius.Text = CStr(dblCelsius)

End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim intEntriesDave As Integer = 0
    Dim intEntriesJoe As Integer = 0
    If radDave.Checked = True Then
        intEntriesDave = +1
    End If
    If radJoe.Checked = True Then
        intEntriesJoe = +1
    End If

    Dim dblAvg As Double
    dblAvg = CDbl(txtTemp.Text) / intEntriesDave + intEntriesJoe
    lblAverageTemp.Text = CStr(dblAvg)

End Sub
End Class
```

Hope I figure this out or I can get some help with it. I procrastinated of course, like the idiot I am, and it is due in 11 hours :\

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a) I think you need an array (or List) to store the values entered b) you are not testing if the input is numeric as required c) there are 9,140 temperature conversion questions here in VB, perhaps you could learn from them.  questions here are generally expected to be a bit more specific than "none of this works"

Comment: What kind of output you're trying to get and missing out?

Comment: looking for 3 outputs. 1) lblAverageTemp 2) lblCelsius 3) Message Box upon closing app. We have only covered 4 chapters of the text and arrays have not been covered yet so I am not too sure on how to keep a running total to average them. The message box as referenced in the code should contain a message stating how many inputs from each technicians were used (essentially how many temp the user enters and selects said technician) as well as the average temp.

Comment: @VBn00b2014 seems like there's no problem with your codes, but what do you mean by "nothing is working". I guess you're having issue with using VB.net to get the GUI done? `"The user will have the option"` and  `"The program will display"`

Comment: @Sky - heres my GUI thus far which i thought was complete - [link](http://i.imgur.com/DG62YbR.png). they are set to false now but there are two other label underneath the text box. when i run the program, enter a temperature and select a technicians, nothing works, as shown here [link](http://i.imgur.com/oxIAEIe.png). Lastly upon exit the summary that is supposed to pop up full of info comes up as this - [link](http://i.imgur.com/IcbHRrQ.png).

Comment: @VBn00b2014 Seems to me that you have a few textbox from your code but I only see one textbox in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary to store names along with temperatures.
Place a numericupdown control on your form for the temperature input (`numTemp`) and a textbox for names `tbName` and a label `lblCelsius` for output:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim temps As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Double))
Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    If numTemp.Value < 32 OrElse numTemp.Value > 80 OrElse tbName.Text = "" Then Exit Sub      'Invalid input
    If temps.ContainsKey(tbName.Text) = False Then 'Name is new, create a new list entry
        temps.Add(tbName.Text, New List(Of Double))
    End If
    temps(tbName.Text).Add(numTemp.Value) 'Append the entered temperature
    lblCelsius.Text = "In celsius: " & CStr(numTemp.Value - 32) * 5 / 9 'Output the Celsius value
End Sub

Private Sub btnStats_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStats.Click
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder 'Create the output
    For Each k As String In temps.Keys
        sb.AppendLine(k & ": " & temps(k).Average)
    Next
    lblCelsius.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    temps.Clear() 'Clear the database
End Sub
End Class
```

Basically everytime you click `btnEnter` you check your dictionary if the name already entered a value. If not a new entry is created with a new list and the new temperature is just added to the list. 
Creating the output is then straightforward with the `.Average` method of the list.